# Delayed requests when using ARR with IIS 8.0 on Windows 2012

Tags: iis, rewrite, iis-8, arr

I've got a setup on Windows Server 2012 R2, using IIS8.0 which passes certain requests through to a custom backend using Application Request Rerouting.

The backend is only listening on IPv4 on port 20000, and my rewrite rule for ARR is as such:

- Pattern: ^BackEndService/(.*)
- Action type: Rewrite
- Rewrite URL: `http://127.0.0.1:20000/{R:1}`
- Append Query String: True
- Stop processing of subsequent rules: True

This should therefore forward requests made from my frontend as, e.g. /BackEndService/getName?user=tom to `http://127.0.0.1:20000/getName?user=tom`

What I'm seeing, however, is a huge delay in the request reaching my backend - 120s.

I've seen this when using Nginx as a test server, but only when proxy-passing to localhost:20000 - proxy passing to     `127.0.0.1:20000` works without this timeout. This leads me to suspect it's an IPv4/6 issue.

Has anyone else seen this before and, moreover, knows how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, in case someone else is having this problem we eventually pinned it down to the "Keep Alive" checkbox in the ARR settings page. After discovered that manually closing the socket on the backend fixed the problem this led us to find the cause in IIS.